# Drupal Services Node Retrieval

Tags: rest, drupal, service

For rest service, I allow for retrieval of nodes. Am I suppose to be able to get the nodes even if I am not logged in. I enabled session authentication but i am still able to get the list of current nodes by just going to the endpoint/node of my Drupal Webiste website.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Anyone with the 'View published content' permission should be able to retrieve a node.

A URL to retrieve a node would look something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/my_endpoint_path/node/123.json
```

The path `my_endpoint/node` refers to the Index resource, which returns a list of nodes.

Here's a complete listing of examples for the Services module: http://tylerfrankenstein.com/user/4/code/drupal-services-examples